# Use variadic template for C callback wrapper

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I am currently trying to wrap a C library (namele its GTK as training). I wanted to see if I can use variadic templated for the callbacks, as they have varying parameter counts in the callbacks for the signal. I intended to use `std::function` and variadic templates. Kind of like this:

```
template<typename... args> class callback_t { public:
    struct cb_data_t
    {
        std::function<void (args...)> callback;
    };
    // data contains cb_data
    static void callback_from_a_c_function(args... a, void *data)
    {
        cb_data_t *cbd = (cb_data *)data;
        cbd.callback(a...);
    }

private:
    cb_data_t cb_data;

};
```

I am pretty new to this, but is this even possible to pass the variadic arguments to a `std:function`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but is this even possible to pass the variadic arguments to a std:function?

I don't understand what you're trying to obtain but... given that the `args...` are fixed as template parameter of the class, yes: you can.

With a couple of corrections in your static method: (1) you have to cast `data` to a `cb_data_t` pointer (no `cb_data`) and (2) you have to take in count that `cbd` is a pointer so you have to call `callback()` through an arrow operator, not through a point operator

```
  static void callback_from_a_c_function(args... a, void *data)
   { // ......................VV
     cb_data_t *cbd = (cb_data_t *)data;
     cbd->callback(a...);
   } // ^^
```

or, maybe better, you can directly pass the last argument as `cb_data_t` pointer

```
  static void callback_from_a_c_function(args... a, cb_data_t * cbd)
   { cbd->callback(a...); }
```

Note that, receiving the `cd_data_t` pointer as argument, you're not using the `cb_data` member.

The following is a full compiling, and simplified, example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template <typename ... args>
struct callback_t
 {
   struct cb_data_t
    { std::function<void (args...)> callback; };

   static void callback_from_a_c_function(args... a, cb_data_t * cbd)
    { cbd->callback(a...); }
 };

extern "C"
 {
   void foo (int, long)
    { std::cout << "foo!" << std::endl; }
 }

int main ()
 {
   callback_t<int, long>::cb_data_t  cbd{&foo};
   callback_t<int, long>::callback_from_a_c_function(0, 1l, &cbd);
 }
```

But this solution seems to me overcomplicated. Unfortunately I don't understand how do you want use your wrapper so I can't suggest you something simpler.